# Databricks Python vs Scala

Tags: spark-streaming, databricks

I have a cluster in databricks. Before importing the data, I want to choose among python vs scala, which one is better in terms of read/write large data from the source?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would choose scala , my two cents on this subject:

Scala:

- supports multiple concurrency primitives
- uses JVM during runtime which gives is some speed over Python

Python:

- does not support concurrency or multithreading (support heavyweight process forking so only one thread is active at a time)
- is interpreted and dynamically typed and this reduces the speed

Also I recommend this article: https://databricks.com/blog/2016/07/14/a-tale-of-three-apache-spark-apis-rdds-dataframes-and-datasets.html

Comment: Using the Python rdd api, reads and writes call the scala method under the hood so it runs in the jvm.  Using the python API for dataframes gets compiled into the same byte code that scala dataframes use.

You can use multithreading with Python on the driver to run multiple jobs at the same time on the cluster.  You can use multithreading in UDF's to do threading on the executors.

The only time Python is slower is when you use UDFs, and even then, using pandas udf's can have better performance than Scala UDFs.

Most of these points you've listed are incorrect.

Answer (score 5):

For the dataframe api, it should be the same performance.  For the rdd api, scala is going to be faster.